# SQL - Get the average of distinct values on each row of view

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, distinct, window-functions

I am needing help returning the current values in my SQL view in SQL Server.

I have a whole lot of columns that are joined by a `UNION ALL` in a SQL view. One of those values is the average pay of that individual over a year.

The current view looks something like:

| Person | Location | Average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 30,000 |
| B | Y | 40,000 |
| C | X | 50,000 |
| D | Z | 30,000 |
| E | Y | 60,000 |

(Please excuse the dummy variables and data)

This average value was calculated from two values in a different table, and has been joined onto the view with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. This means any future calculations based on `[Average]` will be outside the `cte`.

I am now wanting to add another column that obtains the 'Package Average'. This is the average of the average, but only accounting for each value once. In this example, that would be 45,000 (as opposed to 42,000 if we counted for the second 30,000).

I am also wanting this Package Average placed on every line of the view.

I know of `AVG(DISTINCT [Average])` however that requires an aggregate.
I also know of the analytical function `avg([Average])` however that doesn't working with `DISTINCT`.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's mathematically incorrect to average averages. You can't say 60,000 is an average for one thing and 40,000 is an average for another thing and conclude that the overall average must be 50,000. You need to know the population size of both sources - e.g.: when dealing with 1 thing averaging 60,000 and 1,000 things averaging 40,000 the overall average is 40,019.9800. You really need the sum and count of all sources to calculate a correct average.

Comment: The average pay you see there isn't actually a random average, there are only 6 distinct values in the entire database. There are 6 pay scales, all with an average pay, I am wanting the average across all categories. I don't want the package average skewed by the number of individuals at each pay scale, because this value is meant to show the average pay across the size categories, regardless of individuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join to a sub-query that calculates that packaged average.

For example:

> ```
> create view test_view as
> select *
> from (values
> ('A',     'X',    30000), 
> ('B',     'Y',    40000), 
> ('C',     'X',    50000), 
> ('D',     'Z',    30000), 
> ('E',     'Y',    60000)
> ) v(Person, Location, Average)
> ```

> ```
> select v.*, q.*
> from test_view v
> cross join (
>   select avg(distinct average) as PackageAverage
>   from test_view
> ) q
> ```
>
> ```
> Person | Location | Average | PackageAverage
> :----- | :------- | ------: | -------------:
> A      | X        |   30000 |          45000
> B      | Y        |   40000 |          45000
> C      | X        |   50000 |          45000
> D      | Z        |   30000 |          45000
> E      | Y        |   60000 |          45000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2efcab60bf6bd80f04157b223bd08fa7)*

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as you say, there is no `DISTINCT` for window functions. But you can hack it with `ROW_NUMBER`:

- Calculate the row-number per distinct value.
- Conditionally aggregate only those values that have a row-number of 1

```sql
WITH YourView AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        ('A',     'X',    30000), 
        ('B',     'Y',    40000), 
        ('C',     'X',    50000), 
        ('D',     'Z',    30000), 
        ('E',     'Y',    60000)
    ) v(Person, Location, Average)
),
Ranked AS (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.Average ORDER BY Person) AS rn
    FROM YourView v
)
SELECT *,
  AVG(CASE WHEN r.rn = 1 THEN r.Average END) OVER ()
FROM Ranked r;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5be3b9962be346188979156d4d148b75)